# What adjective do you use to describe a movie that is so sad that it is hard to watch?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

What adjective do you use to describe a movie that is so sad that it is hard to watch? Can I describe that movie as heavy?

Answer (score 1):

Heavy is not bad; I would probably use 'heart-wrenching'.

Comment: Would you use *heartbreaking* only for romantic movies?

Comment: I wouldn't say necessarily *only* for romantic movies, but I would probably tend more toward _heartbreaking_ for romantic ones, and _heart-wrenching_ for ones that are sad in a different way, for example a movie about the Holocaust.

Comment: I agree with you (+1)

Answer (score 0):

You could say the film was a **tearjerker**, or that it was **tearjerking**...

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tearjerker

> Tearjerker
>
> A story, song, play, film, or broadcast that moves or is intended to move its audience to tears